# How to show layout moving from left to right with slow speed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How to **animate** a layout moving from

> left to right

on a button click. initially it should be invisible but on button click it should come out from left direction to cover the screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are going to want to layout your view's xml how you'd want it to show in it's final stage.  Then set the visibility to gone.  Then you will create a [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(-100f, 0f, 0f, 0f);  // might need to review the docs
anim.setDuration(1000); // set how long you want the animation

ViewYouWantToAnimate.setAnimation(anim);
ViewYouWantToAnimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Ok i will try this on Monday thanks for the suggestion . Hope it will work and do as i needed.

Comment: Thanks A lot It's working Thank you so much :-) i did this and its working

Comment: public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(key==0){
     key=1;
     TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(-1250f, 0f, 0f, 0f); 
     anim.setDuration(2500); 
     TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(-1250f, 0f, 0f, 0f); 
     anim1.setDuration(2500);

     popup.setAnimation(anim);
     btn.setAnimation(anim1);
     popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.previousnew);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could use setDuration() method of animanion object to adjust moving speed. He're is excample from my code (it's scaling not moving animation, but hope it helps):

```
Animation an2 = new ScaleAnimation(TARGET_SCALE, targetXscale, TARGET_SCALE, targetYscale);
an2.setDuration(SECOND_ANIM_LENGTH);
```

Comment: TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(type, 0, type, targetXdelta, type, 0, type, targetYdelta);
animation.setDuration(SECOND_ANIM_LENGTH);

Comment: Actually i want something like drawer clicking on button layout should come from left side to cover screen and then again clicking on button it should go in.